# Any good Silverlight Video Player tutorial?

Tags: c#, video, silverlight-4.0

I am new to `Silverlight` and I'm required to create a video player on urgent notice. (Story of my life)

The custom video player should play .wmv files uploaded on another server. I've been trying to find tutorials and it's just nowhere to be found.

Can anyone be so kind to point me in the right direction??

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and C#, by the way.

Thanks in advance.

-Mike

Comment: Can I use something like -- 

VideoElement.Source = new Uri("http://mywebsite.com/video.wmv", UriKind.Absolute);

Comment: do mark this as answer if this helps you. Thnaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly go through following article from code project [Silver Light 4 Media player](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SilverlightMVVMVideoPlay.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

for this we need to drop MediaElement in control and do what ever u want, for help go to

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150625091733/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2009/05/04/silverlight-video-player-source-code.aspx)

http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/dd418943.aspxhttp://www.codegod.de/WebAppCodeGod/using-silverlight-to-create-a-video-player-AID389.aspx

do let us if any confusion.
Thanks